# haskellを用いたの計算方法

Tags: haskell

haskellを使って計算をしてみたいと思っているのですが、端末にどうやって入力していいのかわかりません。

例えば、programingというディレクトリーの中に、次のような計算式を書いたとする。

```
mysum2(n)=if n==0 then 0 else n+mysum2(n-1)
```

このとき、はじめに端末には

```
$ cd programing
```

のように入力する。
そのつぎに、どのようなことを入力すれば

```
*Main> mysum2(2)
3
```

のように出力されるのかがわかりません。

Comment: 「cd programming」するということはファイルじゃなくてディレクトリーですよね？

Comment: cd programing ということは、「programing」はファイルではなくて、ディレクトリーですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: ついでに、前回の質問同様「programing」というディレクトリの中に、もしも「111.txt」を作って、その中に[mysum2(n)=if n==0 then 0 else n+mysum2(n-1)]という数式を入力したとする。「111.txt」の内容を計算したいとき、どのようにすればテキストを開けられ計算できますか。（cd programing  ->  cd 111.txt  ではないと思います。111.txtはディレクトリではなくて、テキストなので。）

Comment: 前回の質問は知りませんが、111.txtにmysum2の定義を書いた場合について追記しました

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。言われた通りにやってみたらできました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)か[Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/)をインストールしてください。
2. stackをインストールしたのであれば`stack exec ghci`というコマンドを、Haskell Platformをインストールしたのであれば`ghci`というコマンドを端末に入力してください。
3. 例に挙げていた関数定義 `mysum2(n)=if n==0 then 0 else n+mysum2(n-1)` を入力します。

   - もし`mysum2`を`ghci`に直接、ではなく`111.txt`というファイルに書いていた場合、`:l 111.txt`と`ghci`に入力してください。

     - ※でも、普通Haskellのソースコードの拡張子は`.hs`にしますしそうした方がエディターなどの支援を受けやすいので推奨します。
4. 例に挙げていた関数の使用例`mysum2(2)`を入力します。